# Html text control (DIV not recognizing another div created on the fly??)

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='imgCaption' style='background-color:grey;padding:5px 20px;color:white;'>
</div>
<script language="javascript>
 // lots of codes
$('#imgCaption').html(imgCaption + \"<div style='width:87px; float:right; text-align:right;'>\" + nextImgNum + ' of ' + totalNo + \"</div>\" );
</script>
```

The result are not stable.

**First result**

```
Some caption text                                                         1 of 11
```

**Second result**

```
Some caption text continuing.....................................................
..                                                                        1 of 11
```

**Third result**

```
Some caption text continuing ...............................................
                                                                          1 of 11
```

First and 2nd second result are ok as the caption text and the index text are in the same line..

3rd result is not ok as they are on the different line. and the caption div's background color is not covering the index div.

As a result, the index cannot be seen on the third result..

Any work around??

Tkz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a float issue, try adding `overflow:hidden` to `<div id="imgCaption" />`